# Eliminating color transition effects at the edge of two colors in an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter

I cannot for the life of my remember what this operation is called. The operation is defined such that the pixel under consideration is replaced with the pixel value of highest frequency in the kernel window.

The intent is to eliminate extraneous colors one may find at the edges of other more prominent regions and consolidate to a smaller subset of colors.

For example, consider the flag of Congo:

[image]

If we zoom-in to the boundary between two colors we observe a color-transition effect.

[image]

For my purposes there are only two colors in the above image, but the diagonal shape lends itself to a blend of the boundary colors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called a mode filter since you will replace each pixel with the mode (or most common value) of it's neighbors.

In MATLAB, if you have the image processing toolbox you can easily perform this type of filtering using [`colfilt`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/colfilt.html) which will apply the supplied function within a neighborhood of the specified size.

```
output = colfilt(data, [5 5], 'sliding', @mode)
```

**Update**

If you want to not deal with all of the zero-padding at the edges, you could use `padarray` to apply 3 pixels of padding to each side, then perform the filtering, and then remove the extra 3 pixels from all edges.

```
% Pad with replicates of the data
data = padarray(data, [3 3], 'replicate', 'both');

% Perform the filtering
new = colfilt(data, [5 5], 'sliding', @mode);

% Crop out the padding part
new = new(4:end-3,4:end-3);
```

If you want to generalize this to a kernel of size `n` you could use the following function:

```
function out = mode_filter(data, n)

    pad_size = ceil(n / 2);

    % Pad with replicates of the data
    data = padarray(data, [pad_size, pad_size], 'replicate', 'both');

    % Perform the filtering
    out = colfilt(data, [n n], 'sliding', @mode);

    % Crop out the padded part
    out = out((pad_size + 1):(end - pad_size), (pad_size + 1):(end - pad_size));
end
```

Comment: This is nearly perfect. It seems the only problem I am having with this solution is that the implementation of `colfilt` will 0-pad the edges and corrupt the image in places as a result. I have limited Matlab experience, but are you aware of a method for padding the boundary of an image but only processing the original boundaries so we can avoid the affect of 0-padding?

Comment: @sherrellbc I've added a method to add and then remove the padding to yield a better result.